# Generalized eigenvalue problem with nonsymmetric, positive definite matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be matrices, which

- have real entries,
- are positive definite (i.e. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}: x^\top A x > 0, x^\top B x>0$),
- are **not** symmetric.

Consider the generalized eigenvalue problem
$$ A x = \lambda B x$$
with eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ and eigenvector $x \in \mathbb C^n.$
My question (EDIT): Does a regular matrix $T \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ exist, such that
$$T^* B T = I \quad \text{ and } \quad T^* A T = \Lambda(B^{-1} A),$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\Lambda(B^{-1} A)$ is a diagonal matrix with the complex eigenvalues of $B^{-1} A?$

We know that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ have positive real part. Hence, positive definite square roots $A^{1/2},B^{1/2}$ exist with
$$A=A^{1/2}A^{1/2} \quad \text{ and } \quad B=B^{1/2}B^{1/2}.$$
Maybe this is helpful.

If this statement is wrong, would it be true for $B$ being symmetric? In this case, one can use that $B$ is diagonalizable.

Do you have any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If there exists a matrix $T$ such that both $TBT^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}AT$ are diagonal, then it must be the case that $AB = BA$. This does not necessarily hold for two positive definite non-symmetric matrices $A,B$, nor does it necessarily hold for two positive definite symmetric matrices $A,B$.

Comment: Also, it can only hold that $T^{-1}BT = I$ if $B = I$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I changed the question: $T^*$ instead of $T^{-1}$. Then, the statement is at least true for symmetric $A,B$ and $B$ being positive definite.

Comment: If $T$ is regular and $B$ is not symmetric, then $T^*BT$ cannot be Hermitian and so we can't have $T^*BT = I$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this trivial point! Do you have any idea to prove the statement in the case that $B$ is symmetric? In this case, $B$ is diagonalizable, i.e. $B=U \Lambda(B) U^\top$ with orthogonal $U$. I think that a decomposition of $A$ should be used. Which one?

Comment: The aforementioned statement is wrong for sure, when replacing $T^*$ by $T^\top$. Anyway, I asked a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221671/matrix-product-diagonalizable .