# Matrix product diagonalizable

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Considering a similar question than in [Generalized eigenvalue problem with nonsymmetric, positive definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221425/generalized-eigenvalue-problem-with-nonsymmetric-positive-definite-matrices):
Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be matrices, which

- have real entries,
- are positive definite (i.e. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}: x^\top A x > 0, x^\top B x>0$),
- are **not** symmetric.

Is the matrix
$$ B^{-1}A $$
diagonalizable, i.e. does a regular matrix $T \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ exist, such that
$$ B^{-1}A = T \Lambda_{B^{-1} A} T^{-1}$$
where $\Lambda_{B^{-1} A}$ is a diagonal matrix with the complex eigenvalues of $B^{-1} A?$

**EDIT: In general, this statement is wrong for nonsymmetric $A$ and symmetric $B$, see comments. What assumptions on $A,B$ are needed?**

Would it be true for $B$ being symmetric? In this case, one can use that $B$ is diagonalizable, i.e. $B= U \Lambda_{B} U^\top$ with orthogonal $U \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}.$ Moreover, the matrix $B^{-1} A$ is positive definite. How could we proceed?

Do you have any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried doing any simple $2\times 2$ examples?  e.g. let $A$ be upper triangular with ones on the diagonal and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ above the diagonal and $B$ the same except it has $\epsilon^2$ above the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! Consider
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and hence
$$ B^{-1}A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly, $A,B$ are positive definite. But $B^{-1}A$ is not diagonalizable, since it is a Jordan block.

Comment: For the identity matrix $B=I$, i.e. symmetric $B$, the statement is also wrong.

Comment: this is the power of working through simple examples on your own.  Note: I changed the notation surrounding $\Lambda$ in your post -- the original notation was enormously confusing as it overloaded standard associativity notation for matrix multiplication.  In general you're going to want $A$ and $B$ to be symmetric.  What is the motivation behind this question?  The natural case is when $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian (hence real symmetric) and these problems go away.